# ¿Cómo visualizar imagenes en un slider de tres en tres como una paginación en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un total de 9 imágenes (estoy haciendo un slider) y tengo 3 botones. Cuando hago clic en el botón 1, va a la imagen que está en la posición 1, es decir, se previsualiza la imagen 1 como si fuera la primera. Cuando hago clic en el botón 2, va a la imagen que está en la posición 4, es decir, se previsualiza la imagen 4 como si fuera la primera. Cuando hago clic en el botón 3, va a la imagen que está en la posición 7, es decir, se previsualiza la imagen 7 como si fuera la primera.

Cuando hago clic en el botón 1 comienza en la imagen 1 porque el contador es 0, cuando hago clic en el botón 2 se mueve a la imagen 4 y el contador es igual a 3 y si hago clic en el botón 3 pasa a la imagen 7 y el contador es igual a 6 a su vez debería funcionar al revés, si hago clic en el botón 3, comienza en la imagen 7 y si hago clic en el botón 2, debe moverse a la imagen 4 y si hago clic en el botón 1, comienza en la imagen 1.

Mi intención es que cada vez que hago clic en el botón 1, el contador sea igual a 0 y si hago clic en el botón 2, el contador sea igual a 3 y si hago clic en el botón 3, el contador sea igual a 6, es decir, aumentará en tres el valor cuando la posición del botón sea más alta y disminuirá en tres el valor cuando la posición del botón en el que se ha hecho clic sea más baja.

La variable *i* es la posición del botón en el que se hace clic. La variable *img* es el número de la imagen actual a comparar.

Digamos que se vería así usando `if` pero lo que quiero es hacerlo simplificado:

```
let contador = 0;

if(i == 0){
    // aqui el contador vale 0, contador = 0;
    img[contador].style.background = "#acc2fa";
}else if(i == 1){
    contador = 3;
    imgs[contador].style.background = "#084cf6";
}else if(i == 2){
    contador = 6;
    imgs[contador].style.background = "#031a53";
}
```

Intenté simplificar, pero no funciona porque cuando la condición es igual a 0 no se cumple.

```js
if(i !=0 ||( img % 3 ) == 0){
    contador = contador + 3;
}
```

Comment: por favor, ¿podría incluir el html y, si puede, el css de esa manera, podría entender todo el contexto?

Answer (score 0):

Tu tienes esto

```
if(i !=0 ||( img % 3 ) == 0){
```

Posiblemente tu problema es que necesites ocupar un and `&&`, pero es que pones una variable `img` que no sé de donde sale y que es.

Pero, en cualquier caso la solución es más simple y no necesitas `ìf`:

```
contador = i*3;
```

Cuando:

- i=0 -> contador=0
- i=1 -> contador=3
- i=2 -> contador=6

Que es exactamente lo que tu quieres.